# Add a child to parent node without triggering Mutation Observer

Tags: javascript, html, dom, mutation-observers

I have a `div` DOM node. When I add a child for it, Mutation Observer triggers and change previously added child element. But when I use chrome devtools to change `innerHTML` and add a child manually, Mutation Observer doesn't trigger and child prepends normally. I tried to use `element.prepend(child);`, `element.innerHTML = child + element.innerHTML;`, but all of them trigger Mutation Observer that changes previosly added child element. How can I change parent node via javascript without triggering javascript Mutation Observer?

Comment: Editing HTML in devtools of a parent node removes that node and all of its children from DOM, then recreates all of them anew. As such, all listeners and observers are removed along with the nodes.

Comment: @wOxxOm so I can programmaticly recreate parent node with children to get rid of mutation observer?

Comment: Of course. But it may break functionality of the page if there were listeners attached.